# how to capture regex pattern having neted mathcing between paranthises

Tags: java

I'm having the below example where the level of nesting can be at any level.

Example: `Function.greaterThan(Function.toDecimal(input.a.b),7.2)`

This regular expression `\(([^\)]+)\)` is finding only inner function.
output:`(Function.toDecimal(input.a.b),7.2)`

expected output(two matchings):
1)Function.greaterThan(Function.toDecimal(input.a.b),7.2)
2)Function.toDecimal(input.a.b),7.2

Like this tokenization, I wanted to do for the nested function of any level in java. How to do this.

Comment: I recommend not considering regex for arbitrary nested level structures. Build your own parser or use a library if the format is well known, and only use regex for flat tokens if needed.

Comment: Adding a bit on what @Mena said, In your example, the first `Function` has no `(` before that. Thats why your current regex is not capturing the first part. Even if you add a `(` before, it will still not capture the last `,7,2)` part because the regex find a match the parentheses before that. If you have even more nested levels, it makes it more complicated. In a nutshell, your problem most probably not solvable by only regex. it may need a combination of `Infix notation parser` + regex (if needed) to solve it.

Comment: I’m pretty sure other answers on Stack Overflow have already explained why a regular expression cannot handle arbitrarily nested levels of paired delimiters, based on some hard computer science.  You will be much better off writing your own parser.